# jQuery is not executing .toggleClass() in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

Assume we have this snippet written in jQuery :

```
$("#saveButtonFull").on("click", function () {
    $(".inner").toggleClass("progressBar");
    $(".save").toggleClass('textColorize').html("Saved");
});
```

...which as a result should do this filling **[animation](http://jsfiddle.net/AlbanNurkollari/fs4L3hqc/2/)** of the *"Save"* custom button. It really does! But my platform of working is on **ASP.net** and I have a post-back **'click'** event on the server-side that does CRUD operation in the SQL, in this line of aspx file :

```
<div id="saveButtonFull" class="buttonFull btnBorderGreyOut" onclick="document.getElementById('<%= ButtonA.ClientID %>').click()"></div>
```

How do I accomplish that jQuery runs the click event line-by-line (which in this case .toggleClass() is not being executed!) and also let do server-side executing?

Comment: wrap code in `.ready()`.

Comment: I didn't include the .ready(), it's already in my scrit ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came to the answer , thanks to **[Lorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853717/lorin)**'s advice and help to find my way out of what was missing. The result is that jQuery runs *.toggleClass()* and the server-side does CRUD operation asynchronously, swift and smooth.

I figured out that I was missing a **SriptManager** control in my page and hence added there:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```

Notice that **EnablePageMethods** is set to "*true*" which enabled the user to enter the server-side web method and let it do the code.

And then I removed the *.click()* on the **#saveButtonFull** but instead added the "*onclick*" attribute within the tag itself like:

```
<div id="saveButtonFull" class="buttonFull btnBorderGreyOut" onclick="saveButtonProgress()"></div>
```

Why if you'd ask me? Because it wouldn't fire the .click() event so the pure JS one did the work. Also I learnt that I wasn't able to include non-static members  like TextBoxes inside a Public Static String YouNameIt() web method so I had to arrange an array from the client-side and include it within the "data" attribute of the .ajax() event like :

```
 function saveButtonProgress() {
     if (flag === true) {
         var vargu = [];
         $(".textBox").each(function () {
             var currentTxtBoxValue = $(this).val();
             vargu.push(currentTxtBoxValue);
         });

         $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:49795/UserProfile.aspx/UpdateProfile",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             data: "{'profileArray': '" + vargu + "'}",
             async: true,
             success: onSuccess,
             error: onFailure
         });

         function onSuccess(msg) {
             var success = msg.d;
             console.log(success);
             $(".inner").toggleClass("progressBar");
             $(".save").toggleClass("textColorize");
         }

         function onFailure(msg) {
             var failure = "Error: " + msg.d;
             console.log(failure);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the animation on 'mousedown' event rather than 'click'. :)

Comment: It doesn't work at least whit what I tried to replace click with mousedown/mouseup events.

Comment: Read your comment, you want the animation to be async with server side operation. In this case, you should use AJAX and handle the progress bar animation with the ajax response.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-progress-bar-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx
one more
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8b7513/jquery-progress-bar-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of following:

- Do a serverside event (perform your CRUD operation) and then register an JS function which runs you js code(toggle class) like that:

  ```
      if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
      {
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
              "alert", "alertMe();", true);
      }
  ```

or

- Make the button `runat="server"` and then set the CSS class by accessing CSS property in code behind

or

- Switch to `AJAX` (declare your logic as WebMethod - if it is possible to make it static and call an POST to it where you can handle the crud operation asyncroniosly and toggle css class in the postback js function)

  I hope this can help you

Edit:

I have build up a small example of usage of the first and the third possibilities:

codebehind file:
https://gist.github.com/ostelaymetaule/5b4a5c401d2c7ba7d423
 aspx file(js and styling):
https://gist.github.com/ostelaymetaule/4991c21c31f717152bad

Check this out

Comment: It would be more helpful if you'd provide the 2nd option with AJAX declaration in jQuery as I've tried to set runat='server' and etc. The thing is the client-side jquery animation should run simultaneously (asynchronous) with the server-side CRUD operation once clicked on the respective DOM element (div).

Comment: I'm following your steps with Ajax, twitched the code to my need but it seems that in example 1) the response is not declaed; 2) with no response as parameter give in the onSuccess/onFailure functions, the response from the server is :
POST http://localhost:49795/UserProfile.aspx/UpdateProfile 500 (Internal Server Error)

I made the Public Static String blabla() --> Public String as it wouldnt allow me to inser textbox.Text property because the control is non-static. Could that be the problem?

Comment: For ajax to work you must declare your codebehind function as public static and don't forget the [WebMethod] on top of this. Otherwise it will not work. Then you still have the first variant - to register a js function in your postback event (see the other button in the example). 
Why are you adding a textbox at the runtime? Is this for showing "wait screen" or is that a part of the CRUD logic? Cant you use something else for it?

Comment: The logic I'm trying to accomplish is like this:
ClientSide:
1. User puts some text in any of the textbox-es and then the button becomes visible, out of grey-out.
2. He/she clicks on it --> the CRUD operation should be executed on the server-side at this moment.
3. Also to satisfy the user-friendly look the progress-like-filling button should apply it's class designated for it.

Indeed I've learnt that controls cant be put in a static, I resolved that by making an array in clietside and parsing it in 'data' attribute of .ajax() and on the server-side included it as a 'object parameter'

Comment: Yeah, that's a possible way. I am just not sure if this is secure enough. What if a malicious monkey sends a post to your method? Look into this article http://encosia.com/asp-net-page-methods-are-only-as-secure-as-you-make-them/

Answer (score 0):

Since you've defined the action on the ID of the button, I am assuming this is the only button that needs this action. Modify your javascript function as follows:

```
$("#saveButtonFull").on("click", function () {
    $(".inner").toggleClass("progressBar");
    $(".save").toggleClass('textColorize').html("Saved");
    __doPostBack('<%=ButtonA.ClientID %>','');
});
```

This will invoke the postback for the server side button. In case, __doPostBack does not work, you can also replace it by `document.getElementById('<%= ButtonA.ClientID %>').click();`